# Creating a PCL library PointCloud instance from points expressed in polar coordinates

Tags: g++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have data from a 2D laser range finder, in the form of 360-elements float arrays, each element representing a distance for an angle. So for example, if the 10th element of the array is the value 2.5 that means that at 10 degrees angle, the distance to an obstacle is 2.5 meters.

Given these points expressed in polar coordinates (angle, distance), what's the best way of creating a [PointCloud](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html) instance? I see PointCloud is a templated class, so it depends on the type of [PointT](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/point__types_8hpp_source.html) it contains. Reviewing these types, it seems they are all in cartesian coordinates (x, y, z), sometimes with added info on top. But I couldn't find any native polar coordinate point type. Am I missing it? Is it expected the transformation from whatever coordinates to cartesian to be done outside the library?

Transforming polar to cartesian is straightforward, I just want to know if there's a native, probably more efficient way of doing it within the PCL library (maybe keeping it in polar avoiding conversions altogether, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as known, there is no native way to represent a point in polar coordinates.But Why don't you create your own PointType?
Here is the help doc:https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/adding_custom_ptype.html#adding-custom-ptype